How do I make TimelinePlot labels appear on the left side of the axis?
I have the timelines of two objects to compare. This is my current code:
list = {{{1978, "aa"}, {1979, "bb"}}, {{1977, "dd"}, {1986, 
     "cc"}, {1988, "ff"}}};
TimelinePlot[Apply[DateObject[#] -> #2 &, list, {2}], 
 PlotLayout -> "Vertical", 
 Ticks -> {{DateObject[#], #} & /@ First /@ Catenate[list], 
   Automatic}]


But I want their descriptions to appear on the left and right sides of the axis, for example those yellow labels on the left side of the axis. What should I do?

AxisOrigin -> Right will move your labels to the left. Then you can use Show to combine two different TimelinePlots. However, you will encounter some issues with padding and labels will be cropped ...

@Domen Are you sure AxisOrigin exists?

Sorry, a typo, it's AxesOrigin :)

@Domen Then I get a such result by Show

You can use AxisOrigin -> Center to get the labels on both sides. However, by default, the labels in each group will be alternating between left and right side:
TimelinePlot[Apply[DateObject[{#}] -> #2 &, list, {2}], 
 PlotLayout -> "Vertical", AxesOrigin -> Center, ImageSize -> 150]


I don't think there is any option to change this alternating behaviour, so the only way is to modify an internal function:
System`TimelineChartDump`currentSide = -1;
System`TimelineChartDump`separatePackedSizes[sizes_, "Alternating", o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{r = {{}, {}}},
   r[[System`TimelineChartDump`currentSide]] = sizes;
   System`TimelineChartDump`currentSide *= -1;
   r
];

TimelinePlot[Apply[DateObject[{#}] -> #2 &, list, {2}], 
 PlotLayout -> "Vertical", AxesOrigin -> Center, ImageSize -> 150]



What a magic! Crazy man......

When list={{{1978,"中国改革开放"},{1979,"中国进行国有企业改革"},{1980,"中国推行家庭联产承包责任制"},{1982,"中国正式承认私营经济合法地位"},{2001,"中国加入WTO"}},{{1986,"越南革新开放，并开始国有企业改革"},{1988,"越南实行承包责任制"},{1990,"越南通过《私营企业法》"},{2007,"越南加入WTO"}}}; your code don't work normally?

@yode, it seems to work fine for me in v14.1.

Looks like a difference between versions

@yode, I see. Just remove the last argument o : OptionsPattern[] from my code, and then it should also work in 13.3.
